# how to switch to a new root in flutter without saving the old one in the stack?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

based on the documentation :

> To switch to a new route, use the Navigator.push() method. The push()
> method adds a Route to the stack of routes managed by the Navigator.

but this will cause an issue as if I click the back button it will get me back to the first screen root , so how I prevent that ? when i change the root i don't want the old one to be saved in the root stack

```
Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()))
```

From the docs we see this method will

> Replace the current route of the navigator by pushing the given route and then disposing the previous route once the new route has finished animating in.